# what is the java correponding collection to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: java

coming from .Net world, just want to know what is the corresponding collection to .Net Dictionary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably:

```
Map<String, String> map
```

If you want ordered keys:

```
map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
```

If you want O(1) ops instead of O(lg n):

```
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Interface `Map<String,String>`, implementation classes `HashMap<String,String>` or `TreeMap<String,String>`

Answer (score 0):

You clould use [java.util.Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) which extends `Hashtable` and uses `String` as key and value type.